# How to receive emails via PHP contact form hosted on azure?

Tags: php, azure, contact-form

I'm not receiving emails from my contact form on my website and not sure how to fix this? The website is hosted on Microsoft Azure.  How would I go about resolving this?

The code I currently have is:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['contact_name']) && isset($_POST['contact_email']) 
&& isset($_POST['contact_text'])) {
$contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
$contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
$contact_text = $_POST['contact_text'];
if(!empty($contact_name) && !empty($contact_email) && !empty($contact_text)) {

    $to = 'email@domain.com';
    $subject = 'Message from website.';
    $body = $contact_name."\n".$contact_text;
    $headers = 'From: ' .$contact_email;

    if(@mail('email@domain.com', $contact_text, $body, $headers)) {
        echo 'Thank you';
    } else {
        echo 'error.';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'You're missing something';
     }
   }
  ?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="contact_name">
    Email: <input type="text" name="contact_email">
Message: <textarea name="contact_text" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send">

</form>
```

Thank you.

Comment: start debugging: stop stuffing your programattic fingers in your ears going "lalalalalala can't hear you" - you should NEVER be using `@`. and if you don't get that "error" output, then it's not a php problem. php/mail's job is to walk your envelope down to the street corner and toss it in the mail box. if php gets back home ok, then its job is done and it returns true. you need to look at the mail server's logs to see what happened after that.

Comment: Well, the @ has been covered already, but also your code shouldn't even run because of 'You're missing something'. You need to escape that '.

Comment: if you use @ you'll never know what the problem is. can you even specify gmail smtp. try looking at http://swiftmailer.org/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Web Apps Service doesn't provide the STMP server and also we do not have permission to build one on it, so if you remove the `@`, you may get the exception like: `Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()`.

To send mails from the PHP applications on Azure Web Apps, you can leverage some other 3rd part mail services like SendGrid.

You can easily create a SendGrid Account with Azure management portal. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-sendgrid-php-how-to-send-email/ for details.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.